# How to upload/browse and display image on web page using Hooks in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

when I browse an image, I want to show this in web page using Hooks in react js ?
like this....
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMKT1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with hooks

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange}/>
      <img src={file} />
    </>
  );
}
```